# Можно ли как то получить значения элементов словаря без цикла for

Tags: python

Допустим есть словарь

```
dict1 = {'a' : 1234}
```

Можно ли как то присвоить значения элементов словаря ('a' и 1234) к переменным key и val не используя цикл for

У меня есть код, но он с циклом for

```
for key, val in dict1.items():
    print(key, val)
```

Comment: Что значит "получить"? Напечатать словарь? Для этого есть команда print.

Comment: print (dict1["a"])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы хотите распечатать словарь построчно, советую использовать что-то вроде:

```
import pprint
t = tuple(dict1.items())
pprint.pprint(t)
```

`t` — это преобразованный в кортеж словарь. С помощью функции `pprint` вы можете красиво и построчно его распечатать. Если нужно без скобок — без `for` или спискового включения вряд ли можно это сделать.

Если вы хотите присвоить переменным `key` и `val` все ключи и значения соответственно, воспользуйтесь методами `keys()` и `values()`:

```
key, val = list(dict1.keys()), list(dict1.values())
```

Вообще говоря, почему вам так не нравится цикл for? В нем нет ничего плохого, это одно из центральных ключевых слов в питоне. Если у вас к нему антипатия, можете воспользоваться списковым включением (тот же for, но видоизмененный), например:

```
key = [i[0] for i in dict1.items()]
```

Comment: key, val = list(dict1.keys()), list(dict1.values()), именно так мне и нужно, спасибо!

Comment: @MeClou, так не надо. Лучше так: `keys, values = map(list, zip(*dict1.items()))`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, а чем это лучше? Сложнее только. Или так быстрее?

Comment: Это проще. Один вызов `.items` вместо двух `.keys` и `.values`.

Answer (score 3):

Ещё вариант:

```py
dict1 = {'a' : 1234}
key, value = next(iter(dict1.items()))
print(key, value)
# a 1234
```

Comment: Да, красиво. Не пришло как-то в голову использовать генераторы.

Comment: @Глеб Можно и через список `list(...)[0]`, но это не так красиво, индексирование по конкретным индексам означает явно излишнюю работу перед этим. А вообще генераторы и итераторы - не одно и то же.